# JavaScript setInterval to make AJAX post every X number of minutes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Below is a JavaScript `setInterval` function from a timer script I am working on.

It basically calculates a time on every second.  What I want to do is post this time to the server every 2 minutes with an AJAX request.

I just need help with determining when each 2 minutes is reached so I can insert my AJAX code.

Can someone show me how to determine each 2 minute interval in this code below?

```
timer.interval = setInterval(tick = function () {
    /* Don't do anything if the timer is paused */
    if (timer.paused) return;

    /* Calculate the number of seconds from the startTime */
    var sec = M.max(M.round((Date.now() - startTime) * dir / 1000), 0);

    var val = {
        S: sec,                     /* Total number of seconds */
        s: sec % 60,                /* Seconds */
        M: M.floor(sec /= 60),      /* Total minutes */
        H: M.floor(sec /= 60),      /* Total hours */
        D: M.floor(sec /= 24)       /* Total days */
    };
    val.m = val.M % 60;             /* Minutes */
    val.h = val.H % 24;             /* Hours */
    val.d = val.D;                  /* Days */

    /* Format the timer */
    val.text = (options.format || '%-H{:}%0m:%0s').replace(
        /%(-?)(0?)([dhms])(\s*)(?:\{(.+?)\})?/ig,
        options.replacer || function (match, omit, zero, part, space, forms) {
            /* The value of the selected part */
            var v = val[part];

            /*
             * 'day'      -> [ 'day', 'day', 'day' ]
             * 'day|days' -> [ 'day', 'days', 'days' ]
             */
            (forms = (forms||'').split('|'))[2] =
                forms[2] || (forms[1] = forms[1] || forms[0]);

            /*
             * Return the output text, or an empty string if the value is
             * zero and isn't supposed to be shown
             */
            return !v && omit ? '' :
                /*
                 * Initialize the output text with the value (and optionally
                 * a leading zero)
                 */
                (v > 9 ? '' : zero) + v + space +

                /* Add the appropriate form */
                forms[+(v != 1) +
                    (v != 1 && (v%10 < 2 || v%10 > 4) ||
                        (v > 10 && v < 20))];
        });

    /*
     * If we have an element, put the formatted text inside it
     * (otherwise, set "timerElem" to this instance of tinyTimer, so that it gets
     * passed to callbacks)
     */
    timerElem ? $(timerElem).html(val.text) : timerElem = timer;

    /* Invoke the onTick callback (if defined) */
    (options.onTick || doNothing).call(timerElem, timer.val = val);


}, 1000);
```

Comment: you can use **Counter** for this. means count call and when it reaches to 120 then make ajax call.

Comment: can't you use `setInterval(function(){//pass timer.interval  through ajax},120000)`?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I see, so increment counter and when it reaches 120 make my AJAX call and reset the counter back to 0 so it will start the process over

Comment: @MuhammadUsman that worked!  thanks....if you want to post as answer I will accept

Comment: @JasonDavis thanks answer posted :) please vote up and accept it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a **counter** for this that will count your call and when it will reaches to 120 then make call for ajax to post data.

```
var counter  = 0 ;
timer.interval = setInterval(tick = function () {

   /// your stuff
   counter++;
   if(counter == 120)
   {
       /// make ajax call 
       /// then
       counter  = 0;
    }

}, 1000);
```